# Showing log file contents in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to display my log file contents in text area. I am using XML http request to read the file contents using Web API. The web API function reads the file contents as stream and returns as string to the JavaScript call. But when i display the response text in textarea the formatting is lost. The request accept header is of text\html type , also tried with JSON but with the same issue. 
How can i fix it?

Comment: Instead of \r and \n its showing "\u000d" and "\u000a" respectively

Comment: sounds like the char encoding is off, add UTF to the server's content-type header

Comment: @dandavis with text/html or application/json ?

Comment: I gave accept header as this  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accepts", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");. Why the downvoting of the question>

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom class and assigned the log data to one of the properties in it and gave accept header as JSON , parse it and set it to the textarea.